# Hugo Markdown Footnotes emitting JQuery exception

Tags: jquery, markdown, hugo

I have a Hugo web site that has Markdown content that specifies a [Footnote](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax#footnotes).  The site includes JQuery 3.4.1.

When clicking on a Footnote anchor, a JQuery exception is emitted in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=fn:1]
    at Function.se.error (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at se.tokenize (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at se.select (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.se [as find] (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.find (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at new k.fn.init (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):255)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

The generated HTML code for the footnote link looks like:

```html
<sup id="fnref:1">
  <a href="#fn:1" class="footnote-ref" role="doc-noteref">1</a>
</sup>
```

And the generated HTML code for the footnote looks like:

```html
<section class="footnotes" role="doc-endnotes">
  <hr>
  <ol>
    <li id="fn:1" role="doc-endnote">
      <p>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pineapple">Pineapple</a>
        <a href="#fnref:1" class="footnote-backref" role="doc-backlink">↩︎</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

This looks like standard HTML to me.  Why is JQuery throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the issue down to that fact that I am also using the [Smooth Scrolling CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

The generated code uses [ids as anchors](https://perishablepress.com/ids-are-anchors-too/), yet the *Smooth Scrolling* code does not handle that.

Comment: I ended up replacing the JQuery based Smooth Scrolling CSS Trick with a polyfill approach: https://jonaskuske.github.io/smoothscroll-anchor-polyfill/